# Powershell - windowstyle hidden

Tags: powershell

I m running a ps1 script on powershell. When I run it with the console showing, it works fine. But when I try with - windowstyle hidden, the script does not run. Any help would be appreciated.
I m running from the start menu "powershell -exec bypass -windowstyle hidden". I m testing with a simple Hello world.ps1 script. Without -windowstyle hidden it executes and shows up the hello world, but with the flag, nothing hapens. And it s the most simple script just to test....

Comment: By using `-WindowStyle Hidden`  you're asking to run the script hidden, i.e. _invisibly_ (though a console window still briefly appears, before PowerShell makes it invisible), so it sounds like expected behavior.